# How to fix 'npm does not support Node.js v11.14.0 error' on Windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, npm-install

I am configuring my react-native environment. I am attempting to run the react-native command line as described in Facebook's Github documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

I have installed the latest version of node.js when I type `C:\WINDOWS\system32>node -v` `v11.14.` is returned.

The npm downloaded was included with the latest version of node.js. However it is only 5.5.1. When I input `C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm -v` the result is `5.5.1`

- I've tried to uninstall and reinstall
- I've tried to download the LTS version of node.js
- I've tried to upgrade both node.js and npm
- This is for Windows 10
- This is running from the administrative command prompt and administrative power shell

This is the code

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g react-native-cli
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.15.3
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

When I attempt to clean the cache with `npm cache clean -f` this is the result

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm cache clean -f
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.15.3
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
```

**Edits**
*The following code is a result of some of the proposed solutions*

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g npm
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v11.14.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v11.14.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v11.14.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I expect to open the npm command line interface. I am receiving errors when I attempt to call the interface.

Comment: uninstall global instance of npm by using `npm uninstall -g npm`

Comment: That was initially tried hence this is what I got

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm uninstall -g npm
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v11.14.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
```

Comment: In that case delete npm and npm cache from C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Roaming
Then run `npm i -g npm@next` for the latest version of npm.

Comment: OK this is what I'm working on now. Even though I'm in my administrator account it's saying I don't have permissions when I right click and delete in the roaming folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple solution is upgrade your npm version or second option is downgrade your node version.**

Download older node version from here

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

> **How do I update npm?**
>
> **npm install -g npm**
>
> Please note that this command will remove your current version of npm.
>   Make sure to use sudo npm install -g npm if on a Mac.
>
> You can also update all outdated local packages by doing npm
>   update without any arguments, or global packages by doing npm update
>   -g.
>
> Occasionally, the version of npm will progress such that the current
>   version cannot be properly installed with the version that you have
>   installed already. (Consider, if there is ever a bug in the update
>   command.) In those cases, you can do this

Comment: same erro with npm update -g...I will try remove and install and older version

Answer (score 4):

After installing current NodeJS LTS, I still get
`npm does not support Node.js {version}`.

I deleted all files in `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\` and it works.

Comment: When attemping to delete all content in the "npm" folder, "node_modules" folder (everything else was deleted) could not be deleted as they were current in use. I hit cancel on the message and then tried "npm -v" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted node and npm from C:\Users{name}\AppData\Roaming. Then i reinstalled an older version node.js v10.15.3 and npm 6.4.1.

This brings up a different error so I'll be closing this issue...

```
C:\>npm install -g expo-cli
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dnort\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-15T06_32_09_154Z-
```

debug.log

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of npm. Please upgrade it to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue using npm, so I was thinking about the alternative of npm. And, you might give the yarn a try.

Firstly, going to https://nodejs.org/en/ to download the nodejs with the LTS version.

Secondly, going to https://yarnpkg.com to download the msi file with the stable version.

Note that the current version of nodejs and yarn are 10.16.0 LTS and 1.17.3 respectively.
After installation, you can install your project packages by using `yarn install` instead of `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with latest version.
Remove all the NodeJS installation.
For now npm supports node js versions 6, 8, 9, 10, 11.

Go to [this](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.9.0/) version (or older) download the msi file and then do npm install.